# How to set the ABORT option in SQLite from Tcl when violating NOT NULL constraint

Tags: sqlite, null, abort

I have a TCL script where i generate a SQLite table:

```
DB eval {CREATE TABLE StressDat2( LC int NOT NULL, EID int NOT NULL, Xtens float, Ytens float ) }
```

When I try to write NULL values they get accepted anyhow. How can I from Tcl, when generating my table, set the ABORT option which shall handle writing attempts of NULL values?

Comment: It should be impossible to write `NULL` values into this table. How are you trying to write them?

Comment: DB eval {INSERT INTO StressDat2 VALUES( $SubCase , $EID) }

Comment: And what are the values of `SubCase` and `EID`?

Comment: These are not `NULL` values.

Comment: LC and EID are 2 and 5567 but Xtens and Ytens are NULL. Nevertheless i can insert the row into the db. If I check the table in sqlitestudio the option for what to do on a Not NULL violation is blank, not Abort as i would like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Xtens` and `Ytens` columns do not have a `NOT NULL` constraint.
(The default conflict resolution algorithm is `ABORT`; you don't need to set it.)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how do you insert data into the table. If you also do it with Tcl, you need to be aware, that Tcl doesn't understand the idea of NULL value.

Therefore, this is **WRONG**:

```
set lc ""
set eid ""
set xtens ""
set utens ""
DB eval {INSERT INTO StressDat2 (LC, EID, Xtens, Ytens) VALUES ($lc, $eid, $xtens, $ytens);
```

You're obviously inserting empty strings, not null values. To insert null, use null keyword in SQL statement.

This is **CORRECT**:

```
DB eval {INSERT INTO StressDat2 (LC, EID, Xtens, Ytens) VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Finally, a word about "ABORT" conflict resolution in NOT NULL constraint, that you mentioned. You said this is blank in SQLiteStudio and not "ABORT", as you would like to. Well, the "ABORT" algorithm is a default algorithm used by sqlite when no algorithm was defined, so even you have it blank (default), it means it's "ABORT". Read this for more details: http://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html

Comment: If the variable does not exist, sqlite inserts a NULL into the table. (many db driver use the concept of "non-existing variables are `NULL`" for Tcl)